# C# letter permutation with a prefix word

Tags: c#, cpu-word, permutation

How can I make permutations of 2 letters with a prefix word?

like this:

NAMEaa
NAMEab
NAMEac
NAMEad
NAMEae
NAMEaf
...
...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Can't you simply make all permutation of two letters and prepend "NAME"?

Comment: All letters including arabic, chinese etc....?

Comment: @L.B. don't forget Klingon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get desired result with LINQ:

```
string prefix = "NAME";
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

IEnumerable<string> words = from x in alphabet
                            from y in alphabet
                            select prefix + x + y;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (char c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++)
{
    for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 <= 'z'; c2++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NAME" + c1 + c2);
    }
}
```

BTW, those are not [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Comment: It's permutations with repetition (as opposed to permutations without repetition) but that's still a type of permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with all alphabet and loop over it's indices twice.

Answer (score 0):

That's not permutations, that is combinations.

Put the characters that you want in a string:

```
string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

The number of possible combinations is:

```
int combinations = chars.Length * chars.Length;
```

To get a specific combination (0 to combinations-1):

```
string str =
  "NAME" +
  chars.Substring(combination / chars.Length, 1) +
  chars.Substring(combination % chars.Length, 1);
```

To get all combinations you simply loop through them:

```
string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int combinations = chars.Length * chars.Length;
List<string> result = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < combinations; i++) {
  result.Add(
    "NAME" +
    chars.Substring(combination / chars.Length, 1) +
    chars.Substring(combination % chars.Length, 1);
  );
}
```

Comment: Given the example he gave, he did not continue the sequence for long enough to determine if it was combinations or permutations (they start out identical), and since he *said* permutations, it's logical to assume that's what he wants (with no evidence to the contrary).  Also note that you have implemented a solution that returns permutations, not combinations, so I guess you just mixed the two up ;)

Comment: @Servy: No, sorry, but you are completely of the mark there. Permutations is rearranging, so the possible permutations of two characters, for example `a` and `b` is `ab` and `ba`. This isn't strictly combinations (as that would not contain repeated characters), but it's a lot closer to that than to permutations.